# Is there a proper place to put tailwindcss classes that you explicitly need loaded (besides inline comments)?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have an `array` of colors `gray-200`, `red-200`, `blue-200`, `green-200` that I also need `hover:` and `border-` variants (e.g. `hover:gray-200`).

If I explicitly add a *comment* (`/* ... */`) explicating the exhaustive list of permutations (`hover:gray-200`, `border-blue-200`, etc.), the styles load properly.  Presumably because of (purgeable html?), I can't *just* dynmically create these on the fly (when I do, the CSS doesn't load).

The inline comment feels like an understandable location, but not the ideal spot to put all that.  Is there a "proper" place to do this (like in the config file or something), and if so, how/where?

Forgive the ignorance if this is obvious, I'm new to tailwind.

EDIT: If it matters, I'm using React and NodeJS and yarn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you [cannot](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) build dynamic CSS classes on the fly. In order to work you need to mention somewhere in your app full class name or [safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) it. It can be other file, comment or `safelist` section in Tailwind configuration file

*Please note there are no such utility as `hover:gray-200` etc as you need to be specific what do you colorize (like text - `hover:text-gray-200`, background - `hover:bg-gray-200` etc)*

**1. Pass an array of strings**

Every part will be compiled as it is

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    safelist: [
        'text-gray-200',
        'bg-gray-200',
        'border-gray-200',
        'hover:text-gray-200',
        'hover:bg-gray-200',
        'hover:border-gray-200',
        // ....
    ],
}
```

**2. In a specific file**

Common pattern to create and name file `safelist.txt`, put in a root of your project and watch its content. The content of the file could be any, extension could be any, name could be any, there are only two rules - it should contain full names of required classes (like in example 1) and this file should be included in [content](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration) section

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    content: [
        // source files,
        './safelist.txt'
    ]
}
```

These both methods not ideal as you need to write a lot of classes on your own. However `tailwind.config.js` is still JS file so you can do something like this

**3. Using mapping**

Create an array of required color utilities and map them to generate required class names. This way it can be dynamic

```js
// tailwind.config.js

const colors = ['gray-200', 'red-200']

const safelist = colors.map(color => `text-${color} bg-${color} border-${color} hover:text-${color} hover:bg-${color} hover:border-${color}`)

module.exports = {
  safelist:,
}
```

Still not perfect - sometimes thing can be messy and hard to read but it is simple

**4. Regular expressions**

Finally Tailwind provides you a way to use [patterns](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions) for safelisting

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    // an array of multiple patterns
    safelist: [
        {
            pattern: /(bg|text|border)-(red|gray)-200/,
            variants: ['hover'],
        },
    ],
}
```

Here we're saying safelist combination of background, color, border-color properties with red-200 and grey-200 utilities plus hover variant for all of them. Variants could be any, if you need you should pass breakpoint variants also and combination of them. Take a look

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    // just as example you can specify multiple patterns for each utility/variant combination
    safelist: [
        {
            pattern: /(bg|text)-(red|gray)-200/,
            variants: ['hover'],
        },
        {
            pattern: /border-(red|gray)-500/, // another color
            variants: ['hover', 'lg', 'lg:hover']
        }
    ],
}
```

One last thing about safelisting colors - if you left pattern like this `/(bg|text|border)-(red|gray)-200/` it would safelist all color utilities [opacity](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color#changing-the-opacity) included (`bg-gray-200/0`, `bg-gray-200/5`, `bg-gray-200/10` and so on).

```css
/** part of compiled CSS file */
.border-gray-200 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(229 231 235 / var(--tw-border-opacity))
}

.border-red-200 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(254 202 202 / var(--tw-border-opacity))
}

.border-gray-200\/0 {
  border-color: rgb(229 231 235 / 0)
}

.border-gray-200\/5 {
  border-color: rgb(229 231 235 / 0.05)
}

/** and so on - many-many classes */
```

If you are planning not to use opacity variants, finish your pattern with `$` dollar sign

```js
// tailwind.config.js

module.exports = {
    // an array of multiple patterns
    safelist: [
        {
            pattern: /(bg|text|border)-(red|gray)-200$/, // here is $ - no opacity utilities
            variants: ['hover'],
        },
    ],
}
```

[Here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/LdhEnhGRD9?file=config) - check different types of safelist config and Generated CSS (tab at the bottom - it will show all compiled classes)

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you for this level of detail!